# Change Country Name in google Account

Tags: google-account

I moved from Australia to Canada

and many applications I cannot find in Google Play due to my account's country is still Australia

I googled how to change my account to Canada I found a way to do that

Now I have the option to change from Australia to Canada

but when I choose canada I get this message
[image]

and would never change to Canada.

I waited 4 days and the same message still showing.

How can I change the country?

Comment: it doesn't sound like you can change your country without accepting the limitations in your message (eg: you'll have to reenter your payment methods, forfeiting any Play balance, etc).  This is very specific to googles services, so you may want to check their support services.

Comment: i did, i have enetred my candian CC and accepted this message limitation. waiterd 4 days and still shows Australia nd the exact same message when i change to Canada